# How to send a Query as a body in the POST request in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, artifactory

I am trying to send an artifactory Query as a body to a POST Method.I always get the response as 400(Which is a Bad request).Here is my code.What am I doing wrong here.Query looks good as it works using curl and also using Groovy.

```
host = http://artifactory.com/artifactory
build_url = '%s/api/search/aql' % (host)
payload='{items.find({"repo":"lib","type":"file","path":"builds"}).include("*"}'
response = requests.post(build_url,data=payload,auth=(user:pwd))
print response
```

output:
 **Response [400]**

I am using Python 2.7 and here are the REST API Details

```
Artifactory Query Language (AQL) REST API
Since: 3.5.0
Security: Requires an authenticated user
Usage: POST /api/search/aql
Consumes: text/plain
```

--Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just missing a parenthesis at the end, after `include("*"`. Try this:

```
payload='{items.find({"repo":"lib","type":"file","path":"builds"}).include("*")}'
```

Edit: According to the discussion, the problem was lack of authentication.

Comment: This is just a typo.I was trying to simplify the query while pasting it here and yeah,I tried with the above query,you pasted.That did nt work.Is there anyothet way that post method sends this type of message?

Comment: I'm not sure you need another way of making the call, this one should work just fine. There must be something else inherently wrong with either the request or the server processing. Is there a response body? Could you post the full response, maybe? I suggest you look at your server logs, and if you can't find anything there, maybe you should make some. The server is rejecting your request and the first thing to do would be to find out why. Maybe it's expecting some request header your not giving?

Comment: I got the issue.Thanks for your suggestions.The issue is the user I am using to request the content from that particular repository in artifactory, does not have necessary Permissions.After I gave the permissions to that user  to read the content from that repository,everything looked good.

Comment: Well, in that case I think you are returning the wrong response [status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) from the server. In this case it seems appropriate to return a 401 status code instead. Returning the proper status codes will help you a lot in situations like these. I've edited the answer to include the solution, please accept if you think that solves it.